# SFINAE check for template parameter operators

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae, decltype

Could you tell me why the following code fails to compile (with "no matching overloaded function found" in MSVC):

```
template<typename V>
struct LinearModel { // has basis vectors
    template<typename T = V>
    auto consolidation() const -> decltype(std::declval<T>() += (std::declval<T>() *= double())) {
        V linearCombination;
        // linearly combine basis vectors using += and *=
        return linearCombination;
    }
};

int main(){
    LinearModel<double> lm;
    auto c = lm.consolidation(); // the line that produces the error
    return 0;
}
```

My intention is to define `LinearModel<T>::consolidation()` only for `T` that have `T& operator *=(double)` and `T& operator +=(T)`.

Comment: Did you mean to write `std::declval<double>()` or `double()` instead of just `double`? At the moment, you're trying to multiply a value and a type.

Comment: @Kerndog73 Ah yes. Is there a difference between `std::declval<double>()` and `double()`?

Comment: Probably not. `std::declval` is for types that aren't necessarily default constructible. `std::declval<T>()` is always better than `T()` but if you know it's a `double` then you can just write `double()`.

Comment: @Kerndog73 I fixed that (as in question) but it's still giving the same error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`declval` for `T` returns `T&&`, it is not allowed to assign result of `*=` (or other assignment operations) to R-value.

If you want to get Lvalue use: `declval<T&>()`:

```
    -> std::remove_reference_t<decltype(std::declval<T&>() += (std::declval<T&>() *= double{}))>
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/roqYo2)

Comment: In fact the return type can simply be specified as `V`. I did it the way I did just because I need to check for the existence of `operator*=(double)` and `operator+=(V)`. Knowing this, would you recommend anything simpler?

Answer (score 0):

What I did in the end, based on @rafix07's answer:

```
    template<typename T = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(std::declval<V&>() += (std::declval<V&>() *= double()))>>
    T consolidation() const {
        T linearCombination;
        // ...
        return linearCombination;
    }
```